# react-native-fbsdk post message facebook Graph API FBGraphRequest

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I went through [FBSDK Sharing documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/sharing), but I can't find a simple example where one can just post a simple message to timeline (not a link, not a photo, not a video) using FBShareDialog.
I know I can do it running a web request which essentially does this:

```
POST graph.facebook.com/me/feed?
message="My new post message!"&amp;
access_token={your-access-token}
```

as described in Graph API docs, but again - I want to use ShareDialog to have consistent UI.

How do I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note: All user lower case "post" refers to the act of posting to a users wall. All upper case "POST" refers to HTTP request method.

Facebooks offical react native SDK is located here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/

Note there are three different component:

1. Login
2. Sharing
3. Graph API.

The first two are self explanatory and the examples are provided on the site.

> The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's
>   social graph. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that is used to query
>   data, post new stories, upload photos and a variety of other tasks
>   that an app might need to do.

Facebook Graph API is just a REST API which lets you interact with the fb data via HTTP methods( GET, POST, DELETE etc). react-native-fbsdk just layer on top of it which makes it easier to make these request.

There are two prerequisites to posting to a user time.

1. Ensuring your fb app is correctly setup: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Obtaining a user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts.

Once you have obtained these you can post a message using the react native GRAPH API.

But first lets have a look at how you would do this simply using HTTP rather then the RN-SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed

```
POST /v2.7/me/feed HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
message=This+is+a+test+message
```

According to this we need to make a POST request to the location **/v2.7/me/feed** with the message defined as a paramater.

To finally answer your question how to we post to the users timeline using the react native sdk (). Lets have a look at the rnsdk docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/graph-api

It seems like we need two objects `GraphRequest` (to create a request) and `GraphRequestManager` (to send the request)

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  FBGraphRequest,
  FBGraphRequestManager,
} = FBSDK;
```

Since there is no example provided on how to post to the user wall using these two objects we need to look into the source code:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBGraphRequest.js

We can see from the constructor it takes three parameters:

```
  /**
   * Constructs a new Graph API request.
   */
  constructor(
    graphPath: string,
    config: ?GraphRequestConfig,
    callback: ?GraphRequestCallback,
  )
```

We know the `graphPath = "/me/feed"` from the Graph API docs. The callback will just be a function called upon return of the request. This leaves us with the config object, which is defined in the source as:

```
type GraphRequestConfig = {
  /**
   * The httpMethod to use for the request, for example "GET" or "POST".
   */
  httpMethod?: string,
  /**
   * The Graph API version to use (e.g., "v2.0")
   */
  version?: string,
  /**
   * The request parameters.
   */
  parameters?: GraphRequestParameters,
  /**
   * The access token used by the request.
   */
  accessToken?: string
};
```

So our config object will look something like this:

```
const postRequestParams = {
            fields: {
                message: 'Hello World!'
            }
}

const postRequestConfig = {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            version: 'v2.7',
            parameters: postRequestParams,
            accessToken: token.toString() //pre-obtained access token
}
```

Putting it altogether:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  FBGraphRequest,
  FBGraphRequestManager,
} = FBSDK;

_responseInfoCallback(error: ?Object, result: ?Object) {
  if (error) {
    alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
  } else {
    alert('Success fetching data: ' + result.toString());
  }
}

const postRequestParams = {
  fields: {
         message: 'Hello World!'
      }
}

const postRequestConfig = {
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  version: 'v2.7',
  parameters: postRequestParams,
  accessToken: token.toString()
}

const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
  '/me/feed',
  postRequestConfig,
  this._responseInfoCallback,
);

new FBGraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
```

Comment: Shivam, thank for answering, but as indicated in my question - I don't want to post a link with a comment, but just a message/text to user's timeline. Example: 'Hello World!' and that's it. Does react-native-fbsdkshare have a dialog where this would be possible? Thank you.

Comment: Edited and provided a walkthrough

Answer (score 2):

I posted to facebook with react native 0.43 by above code but i changed on  `postRequestParams`

```
const postRequestParams = {
  message: {
         string: 'Hello World!'
      }
}
```

Here is all of me.

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
        GraphRequest,
        GraphRequestManager,
        AccessToken
} = FBSDK;
class PostScreen extends React.Component {
    postToFacebook = () => {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                (data) => {
                    let tempAccesstoken = data.accessToken;
                    const _responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
                        console.log(result);
                    }

                    const postRequestParams = {
                        message: {
                            string: "Hello world!"
                        }
                    }

                    const postRequestConfig = {
                        httpMethod: "POST",
                        version: "v2.9",
                        parameters: postRequestParams,
                        accessToken: tempAccesstoken
                    }

                    console.log(postRequestConfig);

                    const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                        "/me/feed",
                        postRequestConfig,
                        _responseInfoCallback,
                    );
                    console.log("infoRequest");
                    console.log(infoRequest);

                    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
                });
        }
}
```